# Where are websphere-liberty logs inside a docker container?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

After installing websphere liberty into a docker container, logs are no longer under wlp/usr/servers/server1/logs.

I can tail the log by :

```
docker logs --tail=all -f $id
```

but where are they in the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The websphere-docker image from Docker Hub writes the log files to /logs. This is documented in [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/websphere-liberty/).

Answer (score 0):

Hey inside a docker container, logs will be stored under `/opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/logs` path.